# How to calculate total memory used by one table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, linux, cache

I have `innodb_buffer_pool_size=100GB;`

```
show table status where name='test_tb'\G
```

gives

```
    Data_length: 4686086144
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 5107564544
```

seems index uses 5GB memory.

```
ANALYZE table test_tb;
SELECT
sum(stat_value) pages,
  index_name,
  sum(stat_value) * @@innodb_page_size /1024/1024 "size(MB)"
  FROM
  mysql.innodb_index_stats
  WHERE
  table_name = 'test_tb'
  AND database_name = 'test_dbs'
  AND stat_description = 'Number of pages in the index'
  GROUP BY
  index_name;

+--------+-------------------+---------------+
| pages  | index_name        | size(MB)      |
+--------+-------------------+---------------+
| 286016 | PRIMARY           | 4469.00000000 |
| 150014 | test_key1         | 2343.96875000 |
| 161727 | test_key2         | 2526.98437500 |
+--------+-------------------+---------------+
```

its 8GB.

So which one is accurate?

Comment: The size of the "Primary"-index equals your `data_length`, the other 2 indexes will sum up to `index_length`. InnoDB stores all data in btree-structures (indexes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct; both say the same values.  (Don't divide by 1024*1024; it will be a little more obvious.)

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  That is, they are both in the same BTree structure.  The PK provides the order; the data provides the content.

In your table, the data is ~4GB, including the PK and BTree overhead; the two indexes are in two separate BTrees, adding up to about 5GB.

Comment: So the memory allocation in innodb_buffer_pool_size of this table is roughly 9GB?
What' in separate index btree? for example, the `test_key1 ` index bree. I suppose the data of the columns of `test_key1`, and pointer to PK?

Comment: _Up to_ 9GB of the buffer_pool will be used for these 3 BTrees.  It is a "cache", allocated 16KB at a time, so it may _or may not_ every actually consume 9GB.  The leaf nodes of a secondary index contain the PK values.